# How can I display the client IP address on the server side?

Tags: c

My mini project is on implementing a c socket program where multiple clients send files to two or three servers. i have implemented these. but for handling the client request i need to create a child process is it? how can i do that . like have to handle the request separately.please anybody guide me to do it.

server:

```
int main()
{
int sockfd, new_sockfd,x1,x2,log,n;
int server_len, client_len,len;
int cont,fh,cont2;
int result1;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddress;
struct sockaddr_in address;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;

FILE *ia_address;
char *fname = "/home/shishira/Desktop/packet_capture/info_agent_report.txt";
int buffsize=1024;
char buffer1[1024];
char buffer[1024];
char clntName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))>0)
 printf("\n Socket was created\n");

/*  Name the socket.  */

address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
address.sin_port = ntohs(9734);
server_len = sizeof(address);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, server_len);

/*  Create a connection queue and wait INFO_AGENT_REPORTS  */

listen(sockfd, 5);
while(1)
 {

     char ch;

     printf("\n\n Task agent waiting...\n");

/*  Accept a connection to collect report from INFO_AGENT  */

client_len = sizeof(client_address);
new_sockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);
if (new_sockfd==-1) { perror("Connection Not Accepted!!"); return(1);}
else
{
  printf("\n Information agent is connected\n");
                                                                                             if(inet_ntop(AF_INET,&client_address.sin_addr.s_addr,clntName,sizeof(clntName))!=NULL)
    {
      ia_address = fopen("info_agent_report.txt","a+");  
      fprintf(ia_address,"\nFrom InformationAgent:%s\n",clntName);  
      fclose(ia_address);
    } 
 printf("\n Task agent received the contents and saved it in 'info_agent_report' file");
  log=open("info_agent_report.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_APPEND,0777);
  if(log==-1)
           {
               perror("cannot open info_agent_report file\n");
               return(1);
           }

  do
     { 
        x1=read(new_sockfd, buffer1, 1024); 
        x2=write(log,buffer1,x1);
     }
 while (x1>0);
 close(log);
 close(new_sockfd); 

 }

 /*this is to connect to other   server */
/*  connect socket to the interface server's socket.  */

int interface_sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

serveraddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serveraddress.sin_port = 9735;
len = sizeof(serveraddress);
//len=sizeof(address);


if((result1 = connect(interface_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddress, len))==0)
printf("\n Connecting to the Interface server\n");

if(result1 == -1)
{
perror(" Not able to connect to Interface Server!!!!\n");
}

fh = open(fname , O_RDONLY);  
if(fh==-1)
{
perror(" INFO_AGENT_REPORT File is Not Opened!!\n");
return(1);
} 


do
 {
   cont=read(fh, buffer, buffsize);
   cont2=write(interface_sockfd,buffer,cont);
 }
while (cont==1024);
close(fh);    
printf("\n Task agent has sent 'info_agent_report' file to the Interface Server\n\n");
close(interface_sockfd); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how : ( put this after `accept` ):

```
char clntName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
FILE *output;

if(inet_ntop(AF_INET,&client_address.sin_addr.s_addr,clntName,sizeof(clntName))!=NULL){
   output = fopen("output.txt","a+");  
   fprintf(output,"%s%c%d",clntName,'/',ntohs(client_address.sin_port));  
   fclose(output);
} else {
   printf("Unable to get address\n"); // i just fixed this to printf .. i had it as print before
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. its working now :) but if want to send from other machine , i just have to change the ip address here right? address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

Comment: correct .. it will automatically detect whatever the ip of the client is.

Comment: sir i need to print the client ip address in the output file created by the server. i.e., on each append it has to print the client ip address. how can it be done? . have attached my output.txt file for your reference

Comment: Sir, how can i handle the client request in the server. i mean using child process. but i dont know where and how exactly to use it. sir can u please guide me

Answer (score 3):

[`getnameinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getnameinfo.html) is more new-style.

You use it like

```
char clntName[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
char portName[6]; // I wonder if there is no appropriate constant...

if(getnameinfo(&client_address,sizeof client_address,clntName,sizeof(clntName),NULL,0,NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV|NI_NUMERICSCOPE)==0){
   printf("Client = %s/%s\n",clntName,portName);
} else {
   printf("Unable to get address\n");
}
```

Once you have done so, you won't have any difficulties mixing IPv4 and IPv6 calls.

Comment: nice .. i am going to be using this in some of my code with your permission?

Comment: @sukhvir Of course. This is the standard way of doing this. But be aware that I just edited out two bugs.

Comment: how can i automatically detect the client ip address without mentioning the ip address in the server program? i.e whenever a client machine which is unknown sends the data, my server has to display its ip address. is it possible ?

Comment: @shishira This is exactly the subject. A client can only send data after establishing a connection (in TCP, at least) and this happens during `accept()`. So immediately after `accept()`, you have the client's address which you can display as described.